# What is a Calendar Queue?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, data-structures, simulation, priority-queue

I am working on a building a discrete event simulator.  Wikipedia mentioned that there are several general purpose priority queues that are good for use in DES's.  Specifically, it mentions that a Calendar Queue is a good structure.  I found one pdf (from 1988) that mentions Calendar Queues, but for the most part I can't find anything else out about them.  Would someone mind explaining what Calendar Queue's are, how they're used, and where I might find a sample implementation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Google search finds

Study of Optimised bucket widths in Calendar Queue for Discrete Event
Simulator

http://pioneer.netserv.chula.ac.th/~achaodit/paper5.pdf

which describes Calendar Queues in section 2.

Comment: Thanks - though from that description, it seems like it's just a bunch of evenly spaced priority queues.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, [Brown 1988](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=63045) is the first paper I know of to describe calendar queues, though Brown mentions several authors who preceded him. Below is a relatively complete bibliography of the calendar queue literature along with my notes on each paper. Leave me a comment if you would like copies of any of the publications.

- Vaucher       1975    Comparison of events list algorithms. Presents three new algorithms as well. Inspired Brown1988.
- Henricksen    1977    Events list algorithm - adapts to interval times and performs well with a number of distributions, based on Vaucher and Duval
- Ulrich        1978    Brown1988 claims this is O(1), except for the overflow list
- Jones         1986    Compares priorities queues, has an early version of a calendar queue
- Brown     1988    Introduces Calendar Queue [aka: Sorted-discipline Calendar Queue]
- Davison       1989    Discovers the same, mentions some important improvements, Brown acknowledges the improvements in the same letter and has some thoughts of his own. Davison suggests that Jones 1986 has offered some valuable calendar mechanics
- Ronngren  1991    The Lazy Queue. A calendar queue which has a near, far, and very far future - this enables delayed sorting, which speeds things up considerably in their testing
- Steinman  1994    Event Horizon. Generated events have some probability distribution of when they occur, let's use this to determine what needs to be sorted. Allow for parallel simulation
- Steinman  1996    Event Horizon Part 2. Applies Steinman1994 to event list management. Modifies other data structures for use in CQs.
- Ronngren  1997    Comparison of many different calendar queues. Lazy Queue performs well, but Brown1988 frequently performs better. LazyQ and SCQ have bad worst-case performance, Skew Heap and Sply Tree have best worst-case.
- Oh            1997    Dynamic Lazy Calendar Queue. Improve's conventional CQ's performance over uneven event distributions
- Oh            1999    Dynamic Calendar Queue. Works well with uneven distributions
- Cazzolla  1998    Java implementation of Lazy Queue with analysis (not an academic paper).
- Tan           2000    SNOOPy: Statistically enhanced with optimum operating parameter CQ. Uses statistical tests to make a ebtter bucket. Operates up to 100x faster than DCQ and CQ in certain scenarios
- Hui           Thesis  Bachelor's thesis describing many more details of the Hui 2002 paper along with pros and cons of other calendar queue implementations
- Hui           2002    Future events don't need to be sorted right now; consequently, the priority queue proper's size can be limited, reducing resize overhead.
- Goh           2003    MList. Multi-tier linked-lists eliminate resize operations. Shown experimentally to be at least 100% faster than Calendar Queue, Dynamic CQ, SNOOPy CQ, 2-tier Dynamic Lazy CQ, and 3-tier Lazy Queue
- Siangsukone   2003    Optimised bucket widths in CQ. Demonstrates that bucket width can have significant effects on performance.
- Goh           2004    DSplay. Eliminate costly resize operations. At least 100% faster than other calendar queues.
- Tang      2005    Ladder Queue. Provides stable O(1) performance even under queue distributions with infinite variance. Similar to Lazy Queue, but better.
- Yan           2006    Sluggish calendar queue. When events are mostly inserted in order, it is possible to use some statistical properties to acheive a 2-order speed-up
- Himmelspach   2007    Events have durations - outside the main line of research. Extra functionality was needed, this algorithm provides it but may have limited follow-up work.

Also, we've recently finished describing a variant of Brown's algorithm which should perform better. The description is, I think quite adequate to build an implementation from and sample code is provided in the paper. The publication is entitled `Trading Space for Time: Constant-Speed Algorithms for Managing Future Events in Scientific Simulations` by Lehman, Keene, and Barnes and should be indexed sometime this fall. If you'd like a copy, leave a comment and I will send it to you.

To answer a different part of your question, you can think of a calendar queue as being a priority queue which is optimized for events which will have ever-decreasing priorities. Usually the priorities (times) of the events are binned in some way so as to avoid having to touch all the events in order to insert one (as may happen in certain forms of heap management).

Comment: Hi Richard, I don't suppose I could ask for a copy of your paper? I am working on just such a problem and I did not realise there was still research going on in this area! I have read some of the older papers though. I understand if you are unable to do this, but I just thought I would ask - All the best, Kevin

Comment: I read that Cron implements Franta and Maly's algorithm, do you think Cron might be able to take advantage of this new research?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, do you have a link?

Answer (score 4):

**Definition by [NIST](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/calendarQueue.html):**

> A fast priority queue implementation having N buckets each with width w, or covering w time. An item with priority p more than current goes in bucket (p/w)%N. Choose N and w to have few items in each bucket. Keep items sorted within buckets. Double or halve N and change w if the number of items grows or shrinks a lot.

Paul E. Black, "calendar queue", in Dictionary of Algorithms and Data Structures [online], Vreda Pieterse and Paul E. Black, eds. 24 January 2005. (accessed 2014-03-10) Available from: http://www.nist.gov/dads/HTML/calendarQueue.html